# Is a shifter from Campagnolo compatible with a derailleur from Shimano?

Tags: shimano, derailleur, campagnolo

The Campagnolo Veloce is a ten speed shifter and the Shimano is also ten speed derailleur, so can a shifter be compatible with another brand derailleur, specifically Campagnolo and Shimano?

Answer (score 7):

Not without modifications, because the amount of cable pulled for shifting a single cog is different. If you have to make the combination work, there are hacks such as ShiftMate adapters and Hubbub cable routing that can make it work.

Other thing to consider is that 10-speed cassettes from these two brands are slightly different width, so for best function all three should match.

Comment: For reference, 10s Shimano road shifters pull 2.3mm of cable per shift. Many Campy shifters, including 10s, pull a variable amount per shift, and I believe that 10s Campy averages 2.8mm per click (2.5mm x 5 shifts, 3mm twice, and 3.5mm twice). http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/

Comment: Yes, the answer is on "close enough to work" basis. If you work out the actual movement of the parallelogram, you'll see that it's fiendishly complex but it should be obvious that the actuation ration isn't constant. So, both the exact stepping at shifter and the pattern that Campagnolo uses are already approximations of constant step at derailleur. And of course there are sources that claim that the cog spacing on 11- and 12-speed Campagnolo cassettes isn't constant.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.cornant.uk/info/rear.html

> Advanced indexing techniques
> Campag Ergopower shifters

> You can use these 'drop handlebar' shifters with Campag or Shimano-compatible rear mechs by swapping an internal ratchet, as follows. The table shows which cassettes work with different combinations of Ergopower shifters and rear mechs. For example, 'Shim 8' means 'use a Shimano-compatible 8 speed cassette'.

> Note

> mod 4 : pitch of mech modified by turning its anchor-plate by 90° - method 4 below
> x :         non-standard pitch - respace your cassette with Highpath spacers

> Adjustment :   pull your gear cable tight enough to eliminate redundant clicks in top gear
> [image: table of gear combinations]
> (With thanks to Chris Juden for his 'Shimergo' articles in the CTC magazine.)